Call a sub every time a cell changes
I'm in a workbook with two pages (one called character sheet and another called combat). I have a dropdown menu pulling information from the character sheet and putting the value in cell E2. Cell E2 has been merged and centered from E2:G2.
I'm trying to see that the dropdown menu has changed and paste info below it.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    
    Dim selectedCell As Range

    ' Store the currently selected cell
    Set selectedCell = Selection

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Weapons
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    ' Reselect the previously selected cell
    selectedCell.Select
    
End Sub

The sub I am calling is
Sub Weapons()
    
    ' Define worksheets so thing can get cross referential
    Dim CS As Worksheet
    Set CS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Character Sheet")
    
    Dim combat As Worksheet
    Set combat = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combat")
    
    ' Make a variable for to hit
    Dim TH As Integer
    
    ' Greatsword
    If combat.Range("E2") = "Greatsword" Then
        
        TH = CS.Range("E1") + CS.Range("C8")
        
        With combat
            .Range("E4").value = "2d6"
            .Range("F4").value = CS.Range("E1")
            .Range("G4").value = "Slashing"
            .Range("F3").value = TH
            .Range("G3").value = "To hit"
        End With
    
    ' Eldritch Blast
    ElseIf combat.Range("E2") = "Eldritch Blast" Then
    
        TH = CS.Range("C8") + CS.Range("E6")
        
        With combat
            .Range("E4").value = "2d10"
            .Range("F4").value = CS.Range("E6")
            .Range("G4").value = "Force"
            .Range("F3").value = TH
            .Range("G3").value = "To hit"
        End With
    
    End If
    
End Sub

I don't think its the weapons sub as I can call it with a button that just has Call Weapons in it.
I tried putting this in every page including a new module and This Workbook and couldn't get it to display and of the Debug messages.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E2")) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Change in E2 detected"

        Dim selectedCell As Range
        Set selectedCell = Selection

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Debug.Print "Calling Weapons"
        Call Weapons
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        selectedCell.Select
    End If
End Sub

I did the same thing with the same results with this
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Debug.Print "Calculate event triggered"

    Dim selectedCell As Range
    Set selectedCell = Selection

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Debug.Print "Calling Weapons"
    Call Weapons
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    selectedCell.Select
End Sub

And I've done the same thing with this
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static oldVal As Variant
    Dim newVal As Variant

    newVal = Me.Range("E2").Value

    If newVal <> oldVal Then
        Debug.Print "Change in E2 detected"

        Dim selectedCell As Range
        Set selectedCell = Selection

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Debug.Print "Calling Weapons"
        Call Weapons
        Application.EnableEvents = True

        selectedCell.Select
    End If

    oldVal = newVal
End Sub

These are potential solutions I found while googling.

If nothing works: Where have you put the Event routines? They must be placed into the worksheet module of the sheet where the data is changed, not in a regular module.

This Sheet.xslm ThisWorkbook is at the top of the module

That sounds at if you have put it into the Workbook module - that's the wrong place. It needs to be in the sheet module.

Putting it in the Sheet module didnt seem to help.

A Worksheet Change: Populate Ranges

Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1(Combat)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Weaponize Target
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1, modEvents... (or in the same sheet module)
Sub Weaponize(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const SHOW_MESSAGE_IF_NOT_FOUND As Boolean = True
    
    Dim trg1 As Range, trg2 As Range, tArr1() As Variant, tArr2() As Variant
    Dim Weapon As String, IsNotFound As Boolean
    
    With Target.Worksheet ' Target Sheet ('Combat')
        
        With .Range("E2")
            If Intersect(.Cells, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            Weapon = CStr(.Value)
        End With
        Set trg1 = .Range("F3:G3")
        Set trg2 = .Range("E4:G4")
    
        With .Parent.Sheets("Character Sheet") ' Source Sheet
            Select Case Weapon
            Case "Greatsword"
                tArr1 = Array(.Range("E1").Value + .Range("C8").Value, "To hit")
                tArr2 = Array("2d6", .Range("E1").Value, "Slashing")
            Case "Eldritch Blast"
                tArr1 = Array(.Range("E6").Value + .Range("C8").Value, "To hit")
                tArr2 = Array("2d10", .Range("E6").Value, "Force")
            ' more cases here!
            Case Else
                IsNotFound = True
            End Select
        End With
    
    End With
    
    If IsNotFound Then
        If SHOW_MESSAGE_IF_NOT_FOUND Then
            MsgBox "The weapon """ & Weapon & """ was not found!", vbExclamation
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    trg1.Value = tArr1
    trg2.Value = tArr2
        
ProcExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

